# Scientific notation to decimal notation not working in highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, scientific-notation

I am building a highchart with some ultra small values. My problem is that

> when the number is e-7, the chart doesn't convert the scientific
>   notation to numeric notation.

This is my code.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
  var data = [[1532476800000,9.888550207585507e-7],[1532995200000,9.566888695224366e-7],[1533081600000,9.217248059141058e-7]];
  var options = {
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      type: 'line',

    },
    title: {
      text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
        xAxis:{
        type:'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Fruits Amount'
      }
    },
    series: [{}]
  };
  options.series[0].data = data;
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

});
```

> And if the series number is e-6, then the conversion doesn't have any
>   problem.

Have anyone faced this issue before?

[This is the fiddle for the same.](https://jsfiddle.net/hakkim/s9tow54y/1/)

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the labels in Highcharts simply use the value of the numbers, and that is how Javascript prints these numbers. For example, demonstrating in Node:

```
$ node
> 0.0000009888550207585507
9.888550207585507e-7
> 0.000009888550207585507
0.000009888550207585507
```

So what can you do? You can use `toFixed` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)) to always represent it at a given precision. However, note that this has a limit of about 20, as well as requiring you to chose a specific number and becoming a string. However it is simple ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pws85x9g/)):

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.value.toFixed(8);
        }
    },
}
```

If you use `toFixed` with a too large value you could then start choping of the trailing zeros to get a variable length label, but that might not be the best. A crude example ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pws85x9g/1/)):

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            let strValue = this.value.toFixed(20);

            for(let i = strValue.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if(strValue.charAt(i) != '0') {
                    strValue = strValue.substring(0, i + 1);
                    break;
                }
            }

            return strValue;
        }
    }
}
```